# making a function to calculate average

Tags: calculations

How I can make to create a `\newcommand` to calculate an average between three numbers (can be numbers or numeric variables)?

Usage would be

```
\numberavg{<A>}{<B>}{<C>}
```

Should be expandable to more than three arguments, as in

```
\numberavg{<A>}{<B>}{<C>}...{<n>}
```

Comment: `\usepackage{xfp}` and then `\def\avgthree#1#2#3{\fpeval{(#1+#2+#3)/3}}`: `\avgthree{1}{2}{3}`.

Comment: I need the count the element automatically.

Comment: Please be a bit more specific. In the question you wrote "average between three numbers" and in the comment you like to " count the element automatically". It would help if you provide real code and demonstrate your problem.

Comment: for example, I want a funtcion that calculate the average no matter the amount of element \average{}{}{} or \average{}{}{}...{n}

Answer (score 4):

Another `xparse` / `expl3` solution with the same interface as the answer from Christian Hupfer. It works similar but avoids using temporary variables to stay expandable. This makes it easier to use the result in further calculations. It also returns a well-defined result (0) if the list is empty.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:Nn\__avercalc_plus:n{
  + ( #1 )
}
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\avercalc}{O{1}+m}{%
  \fp_eval:n {
    round(
      ( 0 \clist_map_function:nN { #2 } \__avercalc_plus:n ) / max(1, \clist_count:n { #2 })
      , #1
    )
  }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
How I can make to create a newcommand to calculate an average between three numbers (can be numbers or numeric variables)
\def\foo{4.75}
\def\foobar{3.80}
\def\foobarfoo{10.3}

\avercalc{1.5, 3.5, 4}

\avercalc{}

\avercalc[4]{\foobar,\foo,\foobarfoo}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to use `xparse` and `expl3` features, that applies a comma separated list in order to calculate the sum and then divide by the number of the elements. (It is not failsafe yet, since it does not check empty lists so far.)

The optional argument is meant for rounding numbers.

Please note that my `\avercalc` macro isn't expandable.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\avercalc}{O{1}+m}{%
  \clist_set:Nn \l_tmpa_clist {#2}%
  \fp_zero:N \l_tmpa_fp
  \clist_map_inline:Nn  \l_tmpa_clist {
    \fp_add:Nn \l_tmpa_fp {##1}
  }
  \fp_eval:n { round(\l_tmpa_fp/\clist_count:N \l_tmpa_clist, #1)}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
How I can make to create a newcommand to calculate an average between three numbers (can be numbers or nume

ric variables)
    \def\foo{4.75}
\def\foobar{3.80}
\def\foobarfoo{10.3}

\avercalc{1.5, 3.5, 4}

\avercalc[2]{\foobar,\foo,\foobarfoo}

\avercalc[3]{\foobar,\foo,\foobarfoo}

\avercalc[4]{\foobar,\foo,\foobarfoo}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It's possible make it without use xparse_?

Comment: @AndreyVinajera: The other solution uses `xparse` also, why are you asking only me to do without? It is possible, but I don't see any benefit

Comment: @AndreyVinajera With `xparse` adds benefit. It does not lose anything.