# Retrieving the value of \cs_new:Nn

Tags: expl3, latex3

I am writing a simple command to automatically find the average of a given list of values. I created `\findAverageFunction` to take care of all of the logic (copied from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/425066/167081)). The issue is that I am not able to get the result that is calculated to be stored in a variable using

`\fp_set:Nx \l_total_fp{\findAverageFunction:nn{#1}{#2}}`. I kindly ask what is the issue here and what is the possible fix for it. Thank you!!

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \fp_set:Nn { Nx }

\cs_new:Nn \findAverageFunction:nn {% #1=rounding precision, #2=list of values
  \clist_set:Nx \l_tmpa_clist {#2}
    \fp_zero:N \l_tmpa_fp
    \clist_map_inline:Nn  \l_tmpa_clist {
        \fp_add:Nn \l_tmpa_fp {##1}
    }
    \fp_eval:n {round(\l_tmpa_fp/\clist_count:N \l_tmpa_clist, #1)}
}

\fp_new:N \l_total_fp % Declare a new float-point variable
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\myData}{O{10}m}{
  \findAverageFunction:nn{#1}{#2}
  % NOT WORKING:
  %\fp_set:Nx \l_total_fp{\findAverageFunction:nn{#1}{#2}}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\myData{1,2,3,4,5,6, 99}
\end{document}
```

Comment: you used `\clist_set:Nx \l_tmpa_clist {#2` so your function isn't expandable so should not be used in `\NewExpandableDocumentCommand` or `\fp_set:Nx `

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, thank you for pointing out the issue. What is the appropriate solution in your opinion?

Comment: bit short of time, will answer later if no one else does, you could avoid assignments and just use expansion or simpler add an extra `N` argument and save the result to that, like pgf functions saving result to `\pgfmathresult` which can then be used in expansion

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, take your time and I will be awaiting your answer if no one replies. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find your average by using expansion only and use a different command for storing the result in a variable.

With the *-version you input a macro expanding to a list.

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\findAverage}{sO{10}m}
 {
  \IfBooleanTF { #1 } { \jumaily_average:nV { #2 } #3 } { \jumaily_average:nn { #2 } { #3 } }
 }

\cs_new:Nn \jumaily_average:nn
 {
  \fp_eval:n
   {
    round( ( \clist_use:nn { #2 } { + } ) / ( \clist_count:n { #2 } ), #1 )
   }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \jumaily_average:nn { nV }

\NewDocumentCommand{\definevar}{mm}
 {
  \fp_zero_new:c { l_jumaily_var_#1_fp }
  \fp_set:cn { l_jumaily_var_#1_fp } { #2 }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\usevar}{m}
 {
  \fp_use:c { l_jumaily_var_#1_fp }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\myData}{1,2,3,4,5,6, 99}

\findAverage{1,1}

\findAverage{1,2,4}

\findAverage[3]{1,2,4}

\findAverage{1,2,3,4,5,6, 99}

\findAverage*{\myData}

\definevar{test1}{\findAverage{1,2,3,4,5,6, 99}}
\usevar{test1}

\definevar{test2}{\findAverage*{\myData}}
\usevar{test2}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that `\definevar` can be used with any fp-expression.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I kindly ask if there is the possibility to expand a list, like `\findAverage{\myData}`?

Comment: @M.AlJumaily I reworked the answer allowing for what you wanted.

Comment: Thank you again! Lastly, I kindly ask why you separated the two versions rather than using `ne` instead of `nV` and `nn`?

Comment: @M.AlJumaily I prefer to be precise about what input is expected.

Comment: Thank you!!!!!!

Answer (score 2):

Just for comparison, what we can do with OpTeX:

```
\let\ima=\immediateassignment
\def\replcomma#1,{\ifx,#1,\else\ima\incr\tmpnum +#1\ea\replcomma\fi}
\def\findAverage#1{\ima\tmpnum=0 \expr{(0\ea\replcomma#1,,)/\the\tmpnum}}

\findAverage{1,2,4}            % prints 2.333

\findAverage{1,2,3,4,5,6, 99}  % prints 17.143

\def\mydata{1,2,3,4,5,6, 99}
\findAverage{\mydata}          % prints 17.143

\edef\test{\findAverage{1,2,3,4,5,6, 99}}
\test                          % prints 17.143

\meaning\test                  % prints macro:->17.143

\bye
```